# Is it possible to import a Framework that requires a higher iOS version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app requires iOS 14.0, but this framework I want for a feature, requires iOS 15.0. Is it possible to still support iOS 14.0, or must I requires iOS 15.0 for all users?

For example, for this syntax:

```
import Framework
```

I get:

```
Compiling for iOS 14.0, but module 'Framework' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 15.0
```

I tried

```
#if canImport(Framework)
```

But I think that only works for platform differences (iOS vs macOS)

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get any success with this issue? I have a similar problem